# How to remove an item from all customer cart programmatically

Tags: magento

I want to remove an item from all customers include with guest in magento.

> I did try following code.

```
$quoteCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
                        foreach ($quoteCollection as $item) {
                            $item->delete();
                        }
```

But it removes all items of cart and $quoteCollection did not show each item of cart.

Please help me how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to remove a product with product id 123 :

```
$productId = '123';
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: But it removes '123'  for current user. i want to remove productId '123' from all customer cart including guest.